# Adjust Frame According to Image Height And Weight

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to open image with my desktop app. I want to resize my app's height and weight's according to my image's height and weight.

I can't see any error but my code is not working very well. Btw my photo's values are 600x600 always.

Here is my code.

You can see the coordinates show (39,2)

[image]

But ı want 0,0. I don't want to see blank spaces.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QSlider,
        QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QVBoxLayout)
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtOpenGL import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
import sys

#image_path_str = ''
image_path_str = '3.JPG'

class View(QGraphicsView):
    photo_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene.addItem(self.photo)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path_str)
        self.photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def Hand_drag(self):
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def pixel_pointer(self):
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.photo.isUnderMouse():
                self.photo_clicked.emit(QtCore.QPoint(event.pos()))

        super(View, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = View(self)

        self.btn_hand_drag = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Hand drag", self)
        self.btn_hand_drag.clicked.connect(self.view.Hand_drag)
        self.btn_hand_drag.clicked.connect(self.btn_hand_drag_uncheck_others)

        self.btn_pix_info1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Point 1", self)
        self.btn_pix_info1.clicked.connect(self.view.pixel_pointer)
        self.btn_pix_info1.clicked.connect(self.btn_pix_info1_drag_uncheck_other)
        self.editPixInfo1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo1.setReadOnly(True)

        self.view.photo_clicked.connect(self.photo_clicked)

        slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        slider.setRange(1, 250)
        slider.setValue(100)
        slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.zoom)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn_hand_drag)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn_pix_info1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.editPixInfo1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.view)
        vbox.addWidget(slider)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image viewer")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 700, 728)
        self.view.resize(600, 600)

    def zoom(self, value):
        val = value / 100
        self.view.resetTransform()
        self.view.scale(val, val)

    def btn_hand_drag_uncheck_others(self):
        self.btn_pix_info1.setChecked(False)

    def btn_pix_info1_drag_uncheck_other(self):
        self.btn_hand_drag.setChecked(False)


    def photo_clicked(self, pos):
        if self.btn_pix_info1.isChecked():
                self.editPixInfo1.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))

app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
        app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
w.raise_()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**Note:** I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), instead of asking how to get the coordinates of the click with respect to the image that is the real problem, you ask about adjusting the image that is possibly part of your solution attempt.</sup>

Considering the above, the problem is that event.pos() are coordinates with respect to the viewport but with respect to the image, the logic is to do the transformation as shown below:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if self.photo.isUnderMouse():
        sp = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        lp = self.photo.mapFromScene(sp)
        self.photo_clicked.emit(lp.toPoint())
    super(View, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```